# Trigger only one dropdown menu on button mouse hover

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Based on this example https://github.com/briancodex/react-navbar-dropdown I want to create navigation menu with multiple dropdowns:

[image]

Full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3it51b?file=src%2FDevelopers.js

Looks like there is event listener which triggers the two dropdowns. How only one dropdown can be triggered when I hover on a button with menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` of the `Navbar` component change only one state – `dropdown`.

You need to add different states and methods for show/hide dropdown-components.

Comment: Of course: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zvmd7w?file=src/Navbar/Navbar.js

Comment: I have one more question. Sometimes when I click on a button with dropdown and I move the mouse over the dropdown items the dropdown menu disappears. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the display of both your dropdowns is tied to the same state variable dropdown in your code. Line 59 and 69 of your navbar.js file should have separate variables for displaying payments and billing and have a separate onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave handler.

If that's not clear, I can provide a modified code example for you.

Comment: I have one more question. Sometimes when I click on a button with dropdown and I move the mouse over the dropdown items the dropdown menu disappears. Any idea how this can be fixed? –

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same state value 'dropdown' to check the visibility of both the dropdowns.When onMouseEnter is called setDropdown(true) is getting called,which makes dropdown:true.
Now you are using this value in both payment and billing dropdown checks:
{dropdown && }
{dropdown && }
So,its obvious that both are getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer clearly explained the first issue, I won't go over it again.

I'll explain the second issue mentioned: The dropdown menu disappear when moving the mouse toward the dropdown menu

This is caused by Navbar.css. You have a `grid-gap` attributes which create a gap around each button of the navigation. So when moving the cursor on the dropdown, the cursor go over the gap and the dropdown disappear. Because the gap is not part of the button.
To solve this issue you need to delete the `grid-gap` and use `padding` instead

**src/Navbar/Navbar.css**

```css
...

.nav-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px; << remove this line
  ...
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 10px; << add (if you want the same spacing)
}

...
```

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see improvement?

Comment: It's working for me or maybe i didn't understand the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zabhgc?file=src%2FNavbar%2FNavbar.css

Comment: Ok I copied the code. It's working fine. Thank you!

Comment: Actually there is a mistake, i you want to keep the same spacing you need to add the padding in .nav-item instead of .nav-menu

Comment: Ok, can you update the code example please?